# add entire jsonarray to realm

Tags: android, realm

I am getting arraylist from retrofit with my custom class. I converted the same class to realm by extending RealmObject . How can I write/update the entire jsonarray to realm?

jsonarray:

```
[{"sno":"1","name":"a"},{"sno":"2","name":"b"},{"sno":"3","name":"c"},{"sno":"4","name":"d"},{"sno":"5","name":"e"}]
```

My retrofit callback:

```
Callback<ArrayList<CustomModel>> callback);
```

Retrofit code:

```
 @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<CustomModel> mycustomListModel, Response response) {

                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mycustomListModel);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

CustomModel.class

```
public class CustomModel extends RealmObject {


    private String sno;

    private String name;

 public String getsno() {
        return sno;
    }

    public void setsno(String sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }


 public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: `copyToRealmOrUpdate` also accepts a collection, so the above should just work?

Comment: I have added the data from the custom class. Please look into it and check if it's correct.

Comment: Your getters are and setters are not capitalised correctly. After 0.88 that is not a problem, before it will probably crash. Apart from that it, it looks fine.

Comment: I have updated to 0.88.2 but it's still crashing. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Would you please modify the question and put the crash exception there?